# Git Bash - Multiple Bashrc files?

Tags: linux, bash, git

I opened up Git Bash which is basically a standard bash program. I deleted my `.bashrc` file and my `.bash_profile` file in my HOME directory and restarted the program. However when I type in `alias`, I notice I have aliases.

[image]

Where is Git Bash saving these? There are no more text files (even hidden ones) in my HOME directory. How can I see where it is loading these? Thanks.

Comment: you're probably picking the aliases up from the system defaults -- `/etc/profile` and any files referenced in that script (`/etc/bash.bashrc` is common, as is files in `/etc/profile.d/`).  specifics differ among distributions.

Comment: [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually several files that are opened in the /etc directory. The most likely location is going to be in /etc/bash_completion.d but there are some others,  have alook around /etc/profile.d,  /etc/bashrc, /etc/bashrc.bashrc and so on depending on your distribution.

Comment: Thank you. What's weird is it says that those defaults will not be used if I have a bash profile or bash rc and yet it still uses them despite that. Any how, thank you.